# Javascript div height calculation on Chrome for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to calculate the height of a div in jQuery and then use said height in subsequent styling. I cannot get this to work on mobile Chrome (on all platforms), though it works fine on desktop browsers & iOS Safari.

I am using this jQuery:

```
$('#to-be-styled').css({
    'height' :$('#my-div').height(),
    'overflow' : 'hidden'
});
```

where `my-div` is a div inside `to-be-styled`.

I have tried `$('#my-div').css('height')` as well as `height()` variants (e.g. `outerHeight(true)`) without success.

What function should I use for this to work on mobile Chrome?

EDIT:

HTML used:

```
<div id='to-be-styled'>
    <div id='my-div'>text content</div>
    <div id='something-else'>text content</div>
</div>
```

`my-div` is not hidden and has no styling other than font face & size.

I am not setting the viewport or any other responsive tags in `<head>`.

Comment: Is `#my-div` hidden, by any chance? jQuery has problems accurately calculating the height of hidden elements.

Comment: can you include the relevant HTML, and are you setting the viewport or any other responsive tags in the `<head>`?

Comment: @Mousey HTML is now in the question & I have not set viewport/responsive tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want then you can use media query, jquery is not good solution for mobile browser.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #to-be-styled {
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are saying is completely correct, but I think it's irrelevant here. I assume OP wants to set a fixed height on the container elemenet so that the position of additional inside elements can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: have you write code inside div based on parent div then it automatically adjust, no need to do anything extra.

Comment: Yes, most of the time that works, but problems occasionally arise when you don't have a parent element with explicit height, but everything is a percentage, especially with `max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tedfoo - thanks.  Add this HTML to `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Adding this to CSS may also be helpful: `@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width;}` [source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

The next step for responsive code on mobiles to use add a media query in your CSS, as Sunny suggested. 
However, if you are doing something fairly straight forward it may be enough to just change any fixed pixel sizes to percentages, and to use other scalable values like 'em' to set height.  eg

```
<div style="width:100%">
This goes across the full width of the page.</div>
```

or for a table:

```
<tr style="height:2em"> <!-- this row is double the normal line height-->
```

Viewport will deal with much of what you need. 
If the problem continues then can you inspect to find out what height value is detected or what error occurs?

**Edit for mobiles only**

From your jquery it looks like you want two divs to be the same size, and to not display the contents of `something-else` when using mobiles. To do this you don't need any jQuery, just add this to your CSS, setting the width value to be the largest screen size to be used for this layout.

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px)
{
  #something-else { 
       display :"none";
 } 
}
```

**Edit with javascipt**

If the heights of the `<div>` can change then replace your Jquery with Javascript. Jquery isn't needed because the loaded HTML can be edited dynamically using the HTML Document (DOM) commands and only needs a single line of code.

The name of your `to-be-styled` ID is also a problem: the use of two hypens causes it to fail, so I've renamed it in the code below. The javascript must be included *after* the `<div>`s are created, eg right before `</body>` is a useful place. The code is:

```
<head>
<title>My Code</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div id="to-style">
  <div id="my-div">text content</div>
  <div id='something-else'>something-else text content</div>
</div>
rest of document

<script>
document.getElementById("to-style").style.height=document.getElementById('my-div').style.height; 
</script> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#to-style {
overflow:hidden; 
}
```

The 'side effect' of setting the two heights equally is that `my-div` will automatically try to cram all the text into a space to small instead of using overflow. Set the height to 2px and you will see overlapping text for instance. To fix this you can hide the `something-else` div by adding this code:

```
document.getElementById("something-else").style.display = "none" ;
```

**or** you can add the CSS as in the earlier part:

```
    @media screen and (max-width:450px)
{
  #something-else { 
       display :none;
 } 
}
```

Demo with different fixed initial values for the `<div>`s: http://jsfiddle.net/3jk3rg7a/2/

Comment: This sadly hasn't fixed the problem. The height value detected is that of the combined height of all divs inside `to-be-styled`.